# how to write correct dsn in linux

Tags: mysql, go

i follow this tutorial https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/database-access and i don't know how to connect to mysql in code just to know i done all this:
Create a folder for your code,
Set up a database,
Find and import a database driver

and my problem in this step `Get a database handle and connect` https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/database-access#get_handle

the code

```
// Capture connection properties.
cfg := mysql.Config{
    User:                 "hashem",
    Passwd:               "hashem",
    Net:                  "tcp",
    Addr:                 "127.0.0.1:3306",
    DBName:               "recordings",
    AllowNativePasswords: true,
}
// Get a database handle.
println(cfg.FormatDSN())
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", cfg.FormatDSN())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

pingErr := db.Ping()
if pingErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(pingErr)
}
fmt.Println("Connected!")
```

in this code it should print `Connected!` but it always return errors `Error 1045: Access denied for user 'hashem'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` the user name and password and localhost i think it is correct. and just to know when i login in mysql in the terminal `sudo mysql -u root -p` and require the linux password and i type `hashem` and then require mysql password and i don't type any things here and its login very well and i can do every things well like select and insert. but in the code i can't login

Comment: When using the `mysql` cli program you are logging in with `-u root`. In Go you are attempting to login with `User: "hashem"`. They are clearly different. Are you able, using the `mysql` cli program, to connect using `-u hashem`? If not, then you've got your answer.

Comment: @mkopriva yes i try but not work `-u hashem:hashem@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/recordings?checkConnLiveness=false&maxAllowedPacket=0` and the error `Error 1045: Access denied for user '-u hashem'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the mysql user login. Few steps to break your issue down.

1. If you have created the user and password already, login and check if you have granted the required privileges.

```
$ mysql -u hashem -p
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hashem'@'localhost';
```

If you are not sure, grant all privileges:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'hashem'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

2. Check if you have created the required database.

```
$ mysql -u hashem -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE recordings;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.96 sec)
```

3. Check if the connection string is being generated in the way you want it to be. Print `cfg.FormatDSN()` before connecting and check.

```
username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/database?allowNativePasswords=false&checkConnLiveness=false&maxAllowedPacket=0
```

By your comment, the `allowNativePasswords` is not mentioned in your connection string. For more info on this, check [page@Medium](https://medium.com/@crmcmullen/how-to-run-mysql-8-0-with-native-password-authentication-502de5bac661)

References:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql
2. https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/server/databases/create-a-mysql-database/
3. https://medium.com/@crmcmullen/how-to-run-mysql-8-0-with-native-password-authentication-502de5bac661

Comment: ok i still don't know what is wrong in `mysql.Config` because i try what you say in the terminal but i don't know what to change in the code

Comment: The code seems to be fine to me. Have you checked the privileges list after granting?
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hashem'@'localhost';

Comment: when i try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'hashem'@'localhost';` it return `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'hashem'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` and then i try `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` it return `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)`

Comment: Try dropping the user and recreating,
`sudo mysql -u root` <br>
`DROP USER 'hashem'@'localhost';` <br>
`CREATE USER 'hashem'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`